# load config from app.config if available

Tags: c#, database, app-config

Im new to C# .net programming and sorry if I ask stupid question.

I have setup my programs to load setting from database instead off app.config.

However, I want it to replace the setting from app.config if only the setting available in it.

For example, the setting that will load from database is

- IP_address = 192.168.0.111
- folder_path = /share
- pc_name = pc_dev
- username = developer
- password = developer123

then in app.config I will insert this value

- IP_address = 192.168.0.222

the program will then change the IP_address value that it load from database to the value that I insert in app.config

is there anyway to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use your app.config's appSettings. Add a reference to System.Configuration.

Then your app config should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ipAddress" value="192.168.0.222"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then in your code, get the value from the config by using this:

```
string ipAddFromConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ipAddress"]; // get the value from the appsettings.
```

Then you can replace the value that you got from your DB.

Comment: @HazwanYusof please mark it as an answer if you think this helped you.